# Slack API channels.archive doesn't find channel

Tags: node.js, slack-api

I can succesfully create a new channel. When I want to move my channel to the archive I get a response with as error code channel_not_found while i'm 100% sure my channel name is correct.

Does anyone know why I receive this? I'm using slack-node in Node.js

```
    slackController.slack.api('channels.archive', {
    channel: "#test123"
}, function (err, response) {
    console.log(response);
    return callback("ok");
});
```

[image]

Comment: Update: I've found out that you should not use the channel name but the channel id.

Comment: would be great if you could post the solution as an answer and then mark this question as complete. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I've found out that you should not use the channel name but the channel id. The API documentation wasn't clear about that.